# What is max width and height an HTML document with CSS could be?

Tags: html, css

Out of curiosity :)

Also Could any element hit that Size or would some elements have their own restrictions

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? I can't really tell what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I mean, is there a pixel limitation at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upper bounds in the definition of the language itself.  They define a length value as matching the regular expression, "[0-9]+|[0-9]*.[0-9]+".

Any practical limitation would be governed by the browser.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length defines any "length" value used throughout CSS for defining line-height, text-indent, font-size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think the skies the limit for you. It does depend though on how fast or slow you want your webpage load time to be. (Unless I misunderstand the question.)

[see webpage widths for center or left aligned webpages](http://www.michaelfokken.com/blog/code/web-page-dimensions/)

But maybe this isn't a CSS question?

Comment: Hmm something tells me 10000 px might be the limit I know you can't use text indent or left over that value.  Can't wait to get a browser and try it out!